# Voice call receiving / Can't get call on my server

Tags: twilio

Our customers can phone us and give their feedback. I settled up all things in the Twilio console.

But when Twilio received the call, it didn't request my server (URL is correct). Just no request. So I can't record the call.

How can I solve this problem?

Note: Region is the USA

Comment: show a screenshot of console how did you setup the url?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the [Twilio error logs](https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/debugger/events?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fdebugger%3F__override_layout__%3Dembed%26quickDate%3D24%26x-target-region%3Dus1%26bifrost%3Dtrue&currentFrameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fdebugger%3F__override_layout__%3Dembed%26bifrost%3Dtrue%26quickDate%3D24%26x-target-region%3Dus1)?

Comment: sohail amar, https://i.ibb.co/wSWCnbG/2021-10-19-19-38-08.png

Comment: philnash, no, this link shows no events